# Natural deduction proof / Formal proof : Complicated conclusion with no premise

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

Find a formal proof for the following:

$\vdash [(\neg p \land r)\rightarrow (q \lor s )]\longrightarrow[(r\rightarrow p)\lor(\neg s \rightarrow q)]$

As you can see.
No premise to use.
We have to use assumptions and eliminate them.

This also means no using equivalent formulas.
Because we can easily end the problem by finding a shorter and equivalent formula.

But the problem here specifically asks for a natural deduction/formal proof.
I'm always arriving at the conclusion but my problem is I always have ONE non-eliminated assumption left.

Comment: Please don't ask us to reinvent the wheel.  Tell us what do you have so far so we can identify your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**General Strategy**

Break down what you need to prove according to the introduction rule. This is always possible for conjunction and implication. For a disjunction "$A \lor B$", it may not be possible because sometimes you can prove neither "$A$" nor "$B$", in which case you need to go by contradiction, which is to assume $\neg ( A \lor B )$ and obtain a contradiction, from which you can obtain $\neg \neg ( A \lor B )$ without any assumption and then use double negation elimination. Under the assumption, you still want to prove something of the form "$A \lor B$" but this time it is possible. First assume $A$ and obtain a trivial contradiction. So you can conclude $\neg A$ and proceed.

**Solution (Fitch-style natural deduction)**
$\def\imp{\rightarrow}$

If $( \neg p \land r ) \imp ( q \lor s )$:

If $\neg ( ( r \imp p ) \lor ( \neg s \imp q ) )$:

If $r \imp p$:

$( r \imp p ) \lor ( \neg s \imp q )$.

Contradiction.

$\neg ( r \imp p )$.

If $r$:

If $\neg p$:

$\neg p \land r$.

$q \lor s$.

If $\neg s$:

If $\neg q$:

If $q$:

Contradiction.

If $s$:

Contradiction.

Contradiction.

$\neg \neg q$.

$q$.

$\neg s \imp q$.

$( r \imp p ) \lor ( \neg s \imp q )$.

Contradiction.

$\neg \neg p$.

$p$.

$r \imp p$.

Contradiction.

$\neg \neg ( ( r \imp p ) \lor ( \neg s \imp q ) )$.

$( r \imp p ) \lor ( \neg s \imp q )$.

$( ( \neg p \land r ) \imp ( q \lor s ) ) \imp ( ( r \imp p ) \lor ( \neg s \imp q ) )$.

Comment: These are all valid answers. And I thank you very much for the detailed effort. But what I'm not able to inform you, is that, the problem is forcing me to use only the following rules:

Comment: Sorry I got logged out for some reason.

These are all valid answers. And I thank you very much for the detailed effort. But what I'm not able to inform you, is that, the problem is forcing me to use only the following rules:
AND introduction/elimination.
OR introduction/elimination.
NOT introduction/elimination.
IMPLIES introduction/elimination.
CONTRADICTION introduction/elimination.

So using equivalencies such as $p \rightarrow q \equiv \neg p \lor q$ is  not allowed.

I appreciate the answers, and I will validate these.

Comment: @ex.nihil: Did you read my answer before commenting? I **didn't use** any equivalences. Also, don't **assume** that everyone knows exactly what your rules are, because there are about as many variants of natural deduction as there are authors. However, it should be quite trivial to translate between variants.

Comment: Of course I have, and it looked very similar to my attempt only shorter (which is what I was looking for). Your answer is 100% valid, but like you said it's a different variant. The way I understood your answer is by translating it to the variant I was working with. And as for the method of analytic tableaux, it made me understand the order of the assumptions you took, while non-intuitive, got there concisely. What I sometimes do with long expressions is I work backwards in a sort of "Reverse Mathematics" kind of way. I start with the conclusion and work my way back to the premises.

Comment: @ex.nihil: Right. The tableaux method also shows that for propositional logic you should not have to use each piece of the desired theorem more than a few times (I think twice at most). To get the shortest proof you have to work both forward and backward. The reason for my comment is that in your second comment you said "using equivalences is not allowed" as if implying my answer did so. Also, I do not see why you accepted Brian's answer instead of mine since he didn't answer the question (especially given your complaint about equivalences) while I did!

Comment: My bad, I'm a newborn to this site, so the functionality is still new to me.
I accepted both answers actually and I didn't think I couldn't do that.
I accepted yours first then Brian's, and since only one is allowed, it remained his. Fixed.
Either way, my question has unreasonable constraints (thanks to an unreasable instructor).
And apologies, in my second comment the "no equivalencies" weren't aimed at your answer.
I'll look more into this tableaux method and your guidelines.
Thanks again for the solution.

Comment: @ex.nihil: Actually you'll be surprised to learn that what you think is unreasonable is actually quite reasonable in the world of automated reasoning, because the fact that natural deduction corresponds to the tableaux method (unlike proofs using equivalences) and the fact that the tableaux method can be systematically performed (for propositional logic) means that one can write a program to find the natural deduction proof. Also, you'll be surprised that when you fully understand natural deduction, other aspects of logic will be obvious to you (as you learn more later).

Comment: Kind of makes sense now, because the course is taken from a Computer Science perspective. Even though it's a pure mathematics course, but all engineers, computer scientists and mathematicians are required to take it.
The instructor never explained what or why. I'll be sure to go into detail with this stuff. It's quite interesting. Thanks for the insight.
And you spoke about programs, does this explain why their proofs are somewhat long for somewhat simple conclusions? But the advantage is always getting there right?

Comment: @ex.nihil: The length of proofs is not directly related to what I was saying above. For a statement in propositional logic you can check whether it is true (tautology) by using the truth table, but its size is about proportional to $2^n$ where $n$ is the number of variables. Also, it does not give you a short proof since it is essentially case whacking. In contrast, using the tableax method, every step on a branch eliminates the outermost boolean operation, so it usually requires much less work (especially if you reuse results that you compute in other branches). [continued]

Comment: @ex.nihil: And then the nice thing is that the tableax method translates quite directly to a natural deduction proof. And believe me, almost all mathematical proofs actually do follow natural deduction when you look at their logical structure, even though usually we skip steps or use other rules to make our lives easier. Once you are able to use natural deduction correctly, you won't make logical errors anymore except for careless mistakes, because you can mentally see the logical structure. One extremely common error is accidentally switching quantifiers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35791/discussion-between-user21820-and-ex-nihil).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it, not in full gory detail — three of the steps below appeal to simple equivalences; each has to be expanded to establish the particular case of the cited equivalence:

$$
\begin{array}{r|ll}
\text{step} & \text{Formula} & \text{How obtained} \\
\hline 
1 & (\neg p \land r)\to (q \lor s ) & \text{assumption} \\
2 & \neg(r\to p) & \text{assumption} \\
3 & \neg s & \text{assumption} \\
4 & r \land \neg p & \text{From 2.: $\neg(A\to B) \equiv (A\land \neg B)$} \\
5 & \neg p \land r & \text{From 4.}  \\
6 & q\lor s & \text{From 5. and 1. by MP}  \\
7 & \neg s\to q  & \text{From 6.: $(A\lor B)\equiv (\neg B\to A)$}  \\
8 & q & \text{From 3. and 7. by MP}  \\
9 & \neg s \to q& \text{From 3. and 8. — discharge 3.}  \\
10 & \neg(r\to p)\to (\neg s \to q) & \text{From 2. and 9. — discharge 2.}  \\
11 & (r\to p)\lor (\neg s \to q)  & \text{From 10.: $(\neg A\to B)\equiv (A\lor B)$}  \\
12 & [(\neg p \land r)\to (q \lor s )] \longrightarrow [(r\to p)\lor (\neg s \to q)] & \text{From 1. and 11. — discharge 1.}
\end{array}$$

The steps that use equivalences $(\phi\equiv\psi)$ — 4., 7. and 11. — are shorthand for a sequence of multiple steps which deduce $\psi$ from $\phi$.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt.
But my question was WITHOUT using simple equivalences.
This was the question formalized.
I reached a few minutes ago to a result.
I'll post the answer to the question.
Thanks everyone.

Comment: So eliminate those yourself — that's the easy part, That's what's had you stumped for over 3 weeks?!? Can't deduce $\neg B\to A$ from $A\lor B$ ? I hope that's not the case. Inserting them would just make the answer long-winded. I wasn't using "shorter equivalent formulas". Good luck.

Comment: That WAS the case. See now I agree with you this is a really easy and dull problem IF you can deduce an IMPLIES from OR. But for some reason the formulation of the problem insists that we only stick to 5 natural deduction rules of inference (Introduction/Elimination for AND, OR, IMPLIES, NOT, CONTRADICTION).
It's merely a matter of limiting your comfort with what you can use.
What solved this is using the same assumption way too many times along the proof to get where we want. And yes, this took me 3 weeks (not really, on/off work), merely because  the proof is gigantic. Many thanks BrianO.

Comment: Then my sympathies & also congratulations. Problems like this build character, they say ;)

Comment: @ex.nihil: Actually it's not that hard, but it takes practice to get used to natural deduction. If you've learnt the tableaux method (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux) you'll notice that the steps in natural deduction correspond quite closely to the choices made in the tableaux method.